# R repeat code, crawling result

Tags: r

what is problem in my code?? I dont know how to combine the results.
This code is ups delivery data, and it was troublesome to search for the waybill, so i tried it! But it was difficult.

This is code,

```
library(stringr)
Houseno <- c("1Z30A2920429127213","1Z30A2920429463047","1Z30A2920422913297","1Z30A2920439995052","1Z30A2920423741926")
 Houseno
 for (i in Houseno)
{
 url <- (paste0("https://iship.com/trackit/track.aspx?Track=",i))
 line <- readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8")

 #number
 upshouse <- line[which(str_detect(line,"UPS Tracking Number:"))] 
 upshouse <- gsub("UPS Tracking Number:|<.+?>|\t|&nbsp;", "", upshouse)

 #result
 upsresult <- line[which(str_detect(line,"Status:"))]
 upsresult <- gsub("Status:|<.+?>|\t", "", upsresult)

 #com
 com <- data.frame(NO=upshouse, CP=upsresult)
 print(com)
}
```

this code's result is

```
              NO        CP
1 1Z30A2920429127213 DELIVERED
              NO        CP
1 1Z30A2920429463047 DELIVERED
              NO        CP
1 1Z30A2920422913297 DELIVERED
              NO        CP
1 1Z30A2920439995052 DELIVERED
              NO        CP
1 1Z30A2920423741926 DELIVERED
```

But I want this result to be as follows,

```
          NO            CP
1 1Z30A2920429127213 DELIVERED
2 1Z30A2920429463047 DELIVERED
3 1Z30A2920422913297 DELIVERED
4 1Z30A2920439995052 DELIVERED
5 1Z30A2920423741926 DELIVERED
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your intermediate results to a list, and rowbind them as follows:

```
library(stringr)
Houseno <- c("1Z30A2920429127213","1Z30A2920429463047","1Z30A2920422913297","1Z30A2920439995052","1Z30A2920423741926")

result <- vector('list',length(Houseno)) #initialize list with correct length
for (i in 1:length(Houseno))
{
  url <- (paste0("https://iship.com/trackit/track.aspx?Track=",Houseno[i]))
  line <- readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8")

  #number
  upshouse <- line[which(str_detect(line,"UPS Tracking Number:"))] 
  upshouse <- gsub("UPS Tracking Number:|<.+?>|\t|&nbsp;", "", upshouse)

  #result
  upsresult <- line[which(str_detect(line,"Status:"))]
  upsresult <- gsub("Status:|<.+?>|\t", "", upsresult)

  #com
  com <- data.frame(NO=upshouse, CP=upsresult)
  result[[i]] <- com # add result to list

}

do.call(rbind,result) #rowbind the list to a single dataframe
```

Result:

```
                  NO        CP
1 1Z30A2920429127213 DELIVERED
2 1Z30A2920429463047 DELIVERED
3 1Z30A2920422913297 DELIVERED
4 1Z30A2920439995052 DELIVERED
5 1Z30A2920423741926 DELIVERED
```

Hope this helps!